# Flask in uWSGI causing 500 Internal Server Error just from importing SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

**TL;DR Edit:** I didn't have the correct folder permissions set up.

---

Everything works fine when I run flask via `source venv/bin/activate && python run.py`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

But when I run the same app with nginx/emperor.uwsgi then every hit to the server returns 500. If I comment out the SQLAlchemy import then the page loads, as expected.

---

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752521/uwsgi-flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgres-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-reco) I've tried enabling lazy/lazy-app, but it has no effect. Flask is raising the exception, so nginx/uwsgi is not logging anything.

I've tried utilizing `from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication` but still just getting absolute bare-bones "Internal Server Error" in my browser.

---

Config:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = http
gid = http

socket = /var/run/project.uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = http
chmod-socket = 664

pidfile = /var/run/project.master.pid

master = true
lazy = true
lazy-apps = true

chdir = /srv/http/project
python-path = /srv/http/project
virtualenv = /srv/http/project/venv
module = run
callable = app
plugin = python
home = venv
```

Nothing unusual.

---

`source venv/bin/activate && pip list && deactivate` output:

```
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.0)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (6.0.8)
setuptools (12.0.5)
SQLAlchemy (0.9.9)
uWSGI (2.0.9)
Werkzeug (0.10.1)
```

All the usual suspects are present.

Completely in the dark on this one, anybody know how to debug/handle this?

Comment: Who says it is Flask raising the barebones 500, and not uwsgi?

Comment: Try importing SQLAlchemy within the handler.

Comment: What does your uwsgi start script/command look like? I would suspect it is a uwsgi issue.

Comment: @BryceH uwsgi starts via emperor, the script for my flask app is the 'config' in my post. I've decided just to use apache w/mod_wsgi since it's caveman simple to set up, don't need the features of nginx. I also ran into problems running both werkzeug debug mode and uwsgi simultaneously. Everything just works the way I need it to on apache, so I'm not going to waste too much effort simply getting my server to log, run, and do all the other things a server is supposed to do.

Comment: Having a very similar issue, I can't get it to give my any detail about the error. I'm not using Emperor.

Comment: @ChrisChambers: I've just been trying to reproduce the problem and failing because it all just works for me.  However, I notice that flask.ext is actually a cunning redirection module, which may be failing to find and import the module in this case (and hence returning a 500 error when you try to load the page).  Do you see anything in your uwsgi logs?  For example, if you use [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html#logging-to-syslog) to log everything to your local syslog?

Comment: `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` may solve the problem.

Comment: @chrischambers when it works, are you running as the same user as nginx (often www-user or similar name)?  I'm suspicious that this may be a permissions issue on the directory containing the module you want to import.

Comment: @ChrisChambers For what it's worth, my issue was that my folder permissions were incorrect in var and srv. I'm sorry I can't offer more help, I remember how incredibly frustrating this error was.

Comment: Ah, permissions issue. I'll check that out. As it is, I have a symlink to another folder where my app lives in /var/www/..., and it is owned by me, not www-user. I'll try moving the app into the folder and see if that works.

Comment: Figured it out, completely different issue to that above. It was an issue with sessions and me not having a secret key being defined. Apparently, I have to define it before the `__main__` section or it doesn't get added. Works fine now.

Comment: Maybe this thread sould be marked as solved then...

Comment: I would suggest adding an edit (and possibly an answer) that specifies the issue has been resolved.  I got sent here since this is an unanswered question, and it looks like a solution has been found (although not related to the question).

Answer (score 1):

Do you install *uwsgi-emperor* through the **package manger** as well?

Please make sure you are tracing with correct uwsgi.

Sometimes installing uwsgi from pip and apt make this problem. I myself replace the `/usr/bin/uwsgi` with `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` in `/etc/init.d/uwsgi`.

Also you should check the path permissions and db access if any.