# django conn_max_age and uwsgi

Tags: django, postgresql, database-connection, uwsgi

I'm trying to set django's `conn_max_age` setting.

I'm getting error from uwsgi 
`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`

It seems to be related with [uWSGI, Flask, sqlalchemy, and postgres: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752521/uwsgi-flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgres-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-reco)

The post says to turn on `lazy-apps` option.

I wanted to make sure I found the correct solution to the problem and I googled `uwsgi conn_max_age` but there's no other document mentioning this problem or solution.

If django + uwsgi is a popular combination, and conn_max_age is also a good option to use for production, why there isn't many mention of the caveat.