# Correctly managing postgresql connections in celery task for Flask-SQLAlchemy and Celery

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, Celery and uWSGI.

I know that Flask-SQLAlchemy automatically manages the session for you. I'm not sure how this works with Celery workers, but it seems that when I run a task a second time, I get the following error: DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) server closed the connection unexpectedly.

Here's how I create the app context and celery tasks:

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

It seems that maybe the workers are using the same database connection and after a task completes that connection is not replenished?

It may be related to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752521/uwsgi-flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgres-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-reco)?

I'm not sure how to correctly setup the workers or celery so that they're using new connections to the database..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out, for every process that's using an application context, you must use a new application context. Before, in my `app/__init__.py` I was simply creating the application globally like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

I then changed my app to use create_app like in [this pattern](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/contexts/)

Now, my tasks.py looks like this:

```
from myapp import create_app
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app=None):
    app = app or create_app()
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery()
```

Make sure in your create_app you are calling db.init_app(app).

Comment: I am trying to follow your pattern. How do you start the celery workers in this pattern?