# Error while testing flask with apache bench DatabaseError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac and

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, uwsgi

I'm caught up with a strange behavior of `pyscopg2+flask+uwsgi` . I'm trying to test a flask api using apache bench. For the first 2-3 requests I keep getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

After this two more errors are thrown:

```
OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

And then the requests starts working fine.
I'm using this ab command:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 "my_url"
```

Here's how I'm making the connection to pyscopg2:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
1, 20,
dbname=pg_name,
user=pg_username,
host=pg_host,
password=pg_password)

@contextmanager
def get_db_connection():
    """
    psycopg2 connection context manager.
    Fetch a connection from the connection pool and release it.
    """
    try:
        connection = pool.getconn()
        yield connection
    finally:
        pool.putconn(connection)


@contextmanager
def get_db_cursor(commit=False):
    """
    psycopg2 connection.cursor context manager.
    Creates a new cursor and closes it, commiting changes if specified.
    """
    with get_db_connection() as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            yield cursor
            if commit:
                connection.commit()
        finally:
            cursor.close()

with get_db_cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("myquery1")
    cur.execute("myquery2")
    cur.execute("myquery3")
```

And finally I run this command for uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8081 --wsgi-file my_api.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --callable app
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Does it work if you use a single process? The problem could be due to forking.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752521/uwsgi-flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgres-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-reco) ?

Comment: @code_onkel Yes it does work with single process.

Comment: @KirChou I haven' tried it yet. I'll give it a look.

Comment: @KirChou It started working. Thanks for the link.