# Postgres, sqlalchemy and multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I am relatively new to python multiprocessing and struggling with a lot of problems related to this topic. My newest problem is the combination from multiprocessing, sqlalchemy and postgres. With this combination i sometimes got an

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

After research i found this hint in the documentation:

> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html "It’s critical
>   that when using a connection pool, and by extension when using an
>   Engine created via create_engine(), that the pooled connections are
>   not shared to a forked process. TCP connections are represented as
>   file descriptors, which usually work across process boundaries,
>   meaning this will cause concurrent access to the file descriptor on
>   behalf of two or more entirely independent Python interpreter states.
>
> There are two approaches to dealing with this.
>
> The first is, either create a new Engine within the child process, or
>   upon an existing Engine, call Engine.dispose() before the child
>   process uses any connections. This will remove all existing
>   connections from the pool so that it makes all new ones. "

and this:

> [uWSGI, Flask, sqlalchemy, and postgres: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752521/uwsgi-flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgres-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-reco) "The issue ended up being uwsgi's forking.
>
> When working with multiple processes with a master process, uwsgi
>   initializes the application in the master process and then copies the
>   application over to each worker process. The problem is if you open a
>   database connection when initializing your application, you then have
>   multiple processes sharing the same connection, which causes the error
>   above."

My Interpretation is that when using multiprocessing i have to assure that every process uses a new Engine.
In my child-processes there is only one class which reads and writes to the postgres-db so I decided to define an slqalchemy engine inside the class:

```
class WS_DB_Booker():
    def __init__(self):

        engine_inside_class = create_engine(botpak.bas.dontgitp.bot_engine_string)
        Base_inside_class = declarative_base()
        Base_inside_class.metadata.create_all(engine_inside_class)
        session_factory_inside_class = sessionmaker(bind=engine_inside_class)
        self.DBSession_inside_class = scoped_session(session_factory_inside_class)

    def example_method_to_read_from_db(self):
        try:
            sql_alc_session = self.DBSession_inside_class()
            sql_alc_session.query(and_so_on....
```

This works fine without any problems in the first trials. But i am not sure is this a proper way to define the engine inside a class or can this lead to any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really understandable how you fork your processes or which component does the forking.

What you need to make sure is that you *instantiate the `WS_DB_Broker` class **after the forking!***

If you do it the wrong way (instantiate before fork) then the `Engine` may already have references to some `dbapi` connections in it's `Pool`. See the SQLAlchemy [documentation on working with engines](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#basic-usage) for this.

In order to make your error more apparent you may do something like:

```
import os

class WS_DB_Booker():
    def __init__(self):
        # Remember the process id from the time of instantiation. If the
        # interpreter is forked then the output of `os.getpid()` will change.
        self._pid = os.getpid()

        engine_inside_class = create_engine(botpak.bas.dontgitp.bot_engine_string)
        Base_inside_class = declarative_base()
        Base_inside_class.metadata.create_all(engine_inside_class)
        session_factory_inside_class = sessionmaker(bind=engine_inside_class)
        self._session = scoped_session(session_factory_inside_class)

    def get_session():
        if self._pid != os.getpid():
             raise RuntimeError("Forked after instantiating! Please fix!")
        return self._session()

    def example_method_to_read_from_db(self):
        try:
            sql_alc_session = self.get_session()  
            #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            # this may throw RuntimeError when used incorrectly, thus saving you
            # from your own mistake.
            sql_alc_session.query(and_so_on....
```

Comment: I am instantiating the class after forking. My question was more concerned about defining the engine inside the class.

Comment: If you can ensure that you only instantiate the class once throughout the lifetime of your program then it's ok. Otherwise you have to somehow make sure that you do.